# How to post multiple images in Android?

Tags: android

In my application i want to post multiple images to web component in  Android. I had done this in windows phone 7 by adding boundaries. I want to how i can i add boundaries for Android application. Can i have any sample code for doing so.

Regards,
Panache.

Answer (score 0):

the same idea will work - it's just that you will have to format and construct the body of the post yourself, as I don't think there is an inbuilt class for creating a multipart body in android, but there probably is a class you could grab from somewhere on the web ...